# wrong From email when receive

Tags: phpmailer

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = "test.php@gmail.com";
$mail->Password   = "****";
$mail->setFrom('test@email.com','duy tran');
```

in received email it shows From: duytran gmail .
it means that it use username as From email.must be From: duytran gmail 
Any suggest to fix it ?

Comment: CLIENT -> SMTP: AUTH LOGIN
CLIENT -> SMTP: ZWxpbmV4dC5waHBAZ21haWwuY29t
CLIENT -> SMTP: OEhiZTYyQ2Y=
CLIENT -> SMTP: MAIL FROM:<duy31187@yahoo.com>
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.0 OK x5sm31545701pbw.26 - gsmtp

Comment: Try not to add a proper email.

Answer (score 0):

**You can Refer this code it will help you to use php Mailer class**

```
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $to = "admin@gmail.com";
            $mail->IsSendmail(); // telling the class to use SendMail transport

                $from = $email;
                $headers = "From: <".$from.">\n";
                $headers .= "X-Sender: yourname<".$from.">\n";
                $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n"; // mailer
                $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n"; // Urgent message!
                $headers .= "Return-Path: ".$from."\n"; // Return path for errors
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n"; // Mime type
                $mailBody = "";
                $mailBody = '<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" width="90px;">
                                        <span>Listing For:</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                        '.$businessDetail['companyName'].'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" width="90px;">
                                        <span>Listing Url:</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top">

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" width="90px;">
                                        <span>Email:</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                        '.$email.'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" width="90px;">
                                        <span>userName:</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                        '.$businessDetail['userName'].'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" width="90px;">
                                        <span>Comment:</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                        '.$commentDesc.'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>';

                $mail->Subject   = $mailSub;
                $mail->IsHTML(true);
                $mail->MsgHTML($mailBody);
                $mail->SetFrom($email,'yourname');
                $mail->AddAddress($to);

                if($mail->Send()){
                $variables['success'] = "posted successfully and email is send.";
                }
```

Comment: please debug it properly because it is working fine with my system. I think you are missing with some code.

Comment: I see variable $headers, you created but you didn't use it anywhere Ricky